# Lightweight webserver for running in development without installing system wide

Tags: webserver

I'm looking for some way I can set up my project so that you can run a single command and it would run `npm run serve` and `rails server` and then route `/` to the npm server and everything on `/api` to rails. In production I use nginx for this but I do not want to have developers to have to configure nginx system wide to get the development version working. Is there any portable web server that I can bundle with the repo so no manual configuration is required?

Answer (score 1):

Use Heroku as it lets you deploy, run and manage applications written in Ruby, or Node.js...

It also provides 5 free hosting with sub domain of heroku.. all you need is to create a app on it and a heroku remote on git and thats it.. it would build, run and deploy your app on the heroku server.

I too have added my [application (gif search engine)](https://giphy-love.herokuapp.com) on heroku and its working fine.

You can also add your own commands in `Procfile` to serve your applications.

For more info visit: [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start)